# display data from multiple tables to mvc view does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two unrelated tables. I want to display data from them to my view. I tried to add a class to bring the data to it like the following:

```
public class OrderViewData
{
    public List<EventHome> Events { get; set; }
    public List<Portfolio> Portfolio{ get; set; }
}
```

**EventHome** and **Portfolio** are my tables's names
then I used LinQ select in my Controller to get my list and send it to the view
like this

```
ToddlerEntities db=new ToddlerEntities();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    OrderViewData orderView = new OrderViewData();
    orderView.Events = (from o in db.EventHome select o).ToList();
    orderView.Portfolio = (from o in db.Portfolio select o).ToList();
    return View(orderView);     
}
```

and in my view I tried to bring my list

```
@model List<Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData>
```

and

```
@foreach (var ev in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ev.Events.EventsImg)
}
```

but I get the following error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passing a single instance of `OrderViewData` to the view so your view needs to be

```
@model Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData
```

and then loop through its collections

```
@foreach (var ev in Model.Events)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => ev.EventsImg)
}
```

Side note: There is no real need to make the collections `List<T>` - they could just be `IEnumarable<T>`

Comment: thank you that is helped me but still have this error


{
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData]'.}

Comment: Read the first line of my answer - its `@model Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData` NOT `@model List<Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData>` Your passing a SINGLE instance not a collection

Comment: yes sir but
when I tried it i gut this error
 CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData' because 'Toddlers.Models.OrderViewData' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: OMG Read my answer and use the code exactly as it is - its `@foreach (var ev in Model.Events)`

Comment: you have delighting my day-
I do not know how to thank you-
I'm sorry for my rush
it`s work now
thank you